# what is Docking Framework

Tags: java, swing, awt

I searching for undestanding `Docking Framework` concept in web, but I don't understand its concept and benefit. I see exist several 'Docking Framework' in java such as `Netbeans Platform` or `MyDoggy` or `Sanaware` and etc but I don't understand its benefit.

Do you can explain it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A docking window is one that, as well as being able to be displayed as a normal window, can be snapped into the sides of another window, and then unsnapped and dragged somewhere else.

I think describing them as frameworks is pushing it slightly, they are just GUI widget libraries for creating docking windows. The benefit is that you don't have to write the code yourself.

most of these libraries will have some sort of example/demo which may help you understand better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By your answer I guess it is a wrapper for GUI applications. My guess is correct?

Comment: no, I wouldn't say it was a wrapper as that implies you just code you app normally and then wrap it to get the functionality. with these libraries you would have to change the code for each individual window that you wanted to be dockable